# Problems with views and joins on MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have this SQL, but return just same results, and the empresas table have more than 15,000 rows, if i use JOIN return 170 rows, and if i use LEFT JOIN return 15,000 rows but in much more time:

```
SELECT
`e`.`id_empresa` AS `id_empresa`,
`e`.`nome_fantasia` AS `nome_fantasia`,
`e`.`email` AS `email`,
`e`.`slug` AS `slug`,
`e`.`tags` AS `tags`,
`e`.`endereco` AS `endereco`,
`e`.`telefone` AS `telefone`,
`e`.`site_empresa` AS `site_empresa`,
`e`.`atividade_principal` AS `atividade_principal`,
`e`.`responsavel` AS `responsavel`,
`e`.`observacoes` AS `observacoes`,
`e`.`matriz` AS `matriz`,
`e`.`filial` AS `filial`,
`e`.`template` AS `template`,
`e`.`template_cor` AS `template_cor`,
concat(`c`.`nome`, '/', `c`.`uf`) AS `cidade`,
`c`.`id` AS `IDCIDADE`,
`p`.`plano` AS `plano`,
`p`.`logo` AS `logo`,
`p`.`data_vencimento` AS `data_vencimento`,
sum(`a`.`nota_total`) / count(`a`.`id_empresa`) AS `total`
FROM `empresas` `e`
LEFT JOIN `empresas_avaliacao` `a` ON `e`.`id_empresa` = `a`.`id_empresa`
LEFT JOIN `tb_cidades` `c` ON `e`.`cidade` = `c`.`id`
LEFT JOIN `empresas_premium` `p` ON `e`.`id_empresa` = `p`.`id_empresa`
GROUP BY `a`.`id_empresa`
```

Comment: Do you have a question?

Answer (score 0):

**INNER JOIN** gets all records from one table that have some related entry in a second table

**LEFT JOIN** gets all records from the LEFT linked table but if you have selected some columns from the RIGHT table, if there is no related records, these columns will contain NULL. It returns all rows from the left table, even if there are no matches in the right table.

Comment: I try in the view with where, and this return very fast the results, but this don't resolv my problem